# Unit Testing with a DateTime

Tags: .net, unit-testing, datetime

I am unit testing with a date but the build fails because the date has a timestamp in it. How would I remove it to enable the testing works?

```
 DateTime mockDateTime = new DateTime(2025, 4, 18).Date;
 _dateTimeWrapper.Setup(m => m.Now).Returns(mockDateTime)
```

The mockDateTime returns `4/18/2025 12:00:00 AM` but I only want `4/18/2025`

Comment: using DateTime vs var will result in the same data types. the declaration with var actually just compiles to the same CLR code as though you declared it as a DateTime.

Answer (score 3):

instead of `(m => m.Now)`, have you tried `(m=> m.Today)` instead?

```
DateTime mockDateTime = new DateTime(2025, 4, 18).Date;
 _dateTimeWrapper.Setup(m => m.Today).Returns(mockDateTime)
```

also, DateTimes always have a time component. Are you doing any toString actions in your code? you should probably just check `ToShortDateString()`, which is what will give you just the date part of the datetime:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I commented out the second line to test out if the timestamp doesn't get added

Comment: @ghost_king how are you checking it? If you are looking in the debugger that will always show the time, if you are trying to display it via your program you need to call `.ToShortDateString()` like Nathan said to get the string representation without the time.

Comment: I am using the parameter her: "groupRepository.Setup(mocked => mocked.getAllEventsForGroup(456, mockDateTime, false)).Returns(events);"

Comment: I think if you can give us the full test we might be able to help.. this looks like a particular mocking framework of some sort...